# Any freeware programs for CMYK .tiff?

Tags: inkscape, print-design, export, cmyk

So, I'm a grad student trying to submit a scientific paper for publication. One requirement is that all graphs need to be .tiff with CMYK colors. Graphs were made in R and Inkscape, and that's pretty much everything I've ever used. Googled around a bit, but everyone just talks about photoshop. There's no way my university will spring for a photoshop license for a grad student, nor do I know anyone who has it. Any ideas, preferably free, how this can be achieved? Got them as vector files, currently, easily converted to various other file types... but not .tiff.
Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: i must say that i find your Universitys Adobe policy weird. I mean i work with 4 Universities and they supply on campus licenses to all personel and students (thus I have many adobe accounts). All one needs to do is to be on a campus computer and log to adobe with your university email and it kicks you to your university login. And yes it applies equally to history majors, physics major, cs major and art major. It would seem odd that adobe wouldnt do this as its money in the bank. Grad students and staff can even use it on their own computer.

Comment: Anyway be  careful with auto conversions as the color probably needs to be massaged a bit to not include a the black (K) channel.

Comment: Yes. Krita supports CMYK TIFF export and conversion of RGB images to CMYK. You can also open SVG files in Krita.  If you need ICC profiles for the conversion you can download some for free from the International Color Consortium website at color.org or from [Adobe](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/iccprofiles/iccprofiles_win.html)

Comment: Thank you, Krita seems just what I need.